# set styles of a CRichEditView

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

It's been a while since I've done any work with MFC's and I just got handed a project where I need to add a simple console to show logging messages received by the application. I decided to use a RichEditView because I want to be able to format and color the received messages.

I have been banging my head all day trying to set ES_AUTOHSCROLL and ES_AUTOVSCROLL in my CRichEditView and I just can't get it to work...

I derived a class from CRichEditView called CConsoleView and in CConsolesView::PreCreateWindows I set the style to 
 - ES_READONLY | ES_MULTILINE | ES_WANTRETURN | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL

but this didn't work as expected.

OK... nothing wrong with going back to basics so I've tried this in a simple MFC wizard and it worked and I was expecting this to work in my app as well.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775464(v=vs.85).aspx I know that autoscroll can't be changed after the object creation so I guess my object is being created before I call get the call to PreCreateWindow...

- Can I force the style in my CConsoleView constructor?
- When/where is (generic question) the CRichEditView::Create() method being called? shouldn't it be called after PreCreateWindow?
- Besides attaching a new object is there any way to get around this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the control in a dialog template, just add the create flags to the resource file that's declaring the control in dialog.  If you're dynamically creating the control, you'd be doing the Create... unless you're doing MDI (which doesn't seem to fit based on your description).